# Passing views between Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-view

i've got a "simple" question:
How do i pass a view from an Activity to another?

**In my case:**

I've got a MainActivity with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` In this activity_main i've declared a Relativelayout, whose Backgroundcolor I wanna change from another Activity, that gets its `setContentView` from an .xml file, where you cant find this RelativeLayout. How do i do that?

Thanks for the quick answer!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            //Save the text of the editText
            bringer = savedInstanceState.getString("bringer");

            input.setText(bringer);

            //Save the Listview
            content = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("content");

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content);

            layout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.layout);


            layout.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putStringArrayList("content", content);
        outState.putStringArrayList("list", list);

        bringer = input.getText().toString();
        outState.putString("bringer", bringer);
    }
```

**Second Activity:**

```
public class pop extends Activity {

        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Thats where it fails, because it couldnt get the parent-
       view.
                finish();
            }
        });

        sure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you **can't** pass a `View` between activities.

If you have a `View` in `ActivityOne` that you want to modify based on the user's actions in `ActivityTwo`, then you should have `ActivityOne` launch `ActivityTwo` using `startActivityForResult()`.

`ActivityTwo` can then call the `setResult()` method, and `ActivityOne` can implement `onActivityResult()` to receive that info.

Comment: Ty man! But when does the `onActivityResult` get called? Caus my scnd activity just gets finisehd() so and doesnt call the first activity again... @Ben P.

Comment: If you start the second activity using `startActivityForResult()`, and if the only thing you do is call `finish()` in the second activity, you should still see your first activity's `onActivityResult()` method get called by the system (though the `resultCode` will be `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`). If you want to actually pass data back first, you have to call `setResult()` in your second activity before calling `finish()`.